# Is "wear collar and tie" an idiom?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I found this in this sentence:

> He wears collar and tie for work.

If I don't think of this as an idiom, I presume that he wears something that has a collar and a tie separately from it.

Comment: But this is an idiom, it means _He wears a suit for work_

Comment: Wouldn't you generally say *"He wears **a** collar and tie"*. I think you have to count it as an idiom, because it's left over from the days when collars were detachable. Nowadays, collars are always attached to shirts.

Comment: However, while it does mean **shirt** and tie, it doesn't mean **suit**. The trousers (and jacket, if any) worn with a shirt and tie need not be a suit.

Comment: Presumably he has a *white collar job*, to use another idiom.

Comment: @St John of the Cross Could you please show a reference for that? Of course a shirt and tie can be worn with a sports jacket and jeans, but I assumed it was implied here that _collar and tie_ stand for an actual suit.

Comment: Not sure how there can be a reference for an idiom, but that's how it's used in my office. "Collar and tie" does not imply "suit". It does imply wearing a tie (which means a shirt with a suitable collar is necessary).

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked here. Is "collar and tie" an idiom? Arguably so, since it normally refers to an entire dress code, rather than just those two items. Does it matter that OP's citation doesn't include the article? Not really, since just the three words "collar and tie" are enough of a cliché to stand alone as a "singular noun phrase". Or indeed as an adjective - *"He has a collar and tie job"*, for example. I think the question is Not Constructive.

Comment: The "collar" here refers to a "collared" shirt—i.e., one having a collar that could take a tie, i.e., not a tee shirt or polo shirt.

Answer (score 1):

In a strict sense *wear a collar and tie* isn't an idiom.

The most near one is collar and tie men & collar and tie and in loose terms you can refer wearing a collar and tie like a idiom.

*collar-and-tie men* >> businessmen who wear dress shirts and ties.

Example:

- After Jim graduated from college, he went off to join the collar-and-tie men.
- Us working folks at the plant have an awful time getting the collar-and-tie men to see our point of view.

You may find a occurrence here:

> Don't dress casually tonight. It's going to be a collar and tie occasion.

Note: Wearing a collar and tie /historical edge

> A working man often wore his shirt without a collar informally,
>   putting on the collar and tie for a more formal occasion, such as for
>   Church, or going out with his wife. The idiom stems from the days when
>   shirt collars were separate, and came in pairs, two to each shirt,
>   which also saved on laundry, hence another idiom 'be sure to wear a
>   clean collar'.

Comment: I wonder if I could rephrase my sentence as "He wears formal clothes for work".

Comment: @Dragon Buster, ??